# Removing background

Tags: matlab

```
mg = im2double(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuiEt.jpg')); % read image and convert it to double in range [0..1]
b = sum( (1-img).^2, 3 ); % check how far each pixel from "white"

% display
figure; imshow( b > .5 ); title('non background pixels'); 

% use regionprops to get the bounding box
st = regionprops( double( b > .5 ), 'BoundingBox' ); % convert to double to avoid bwlabel of logical input

rect = st.BoundingBox; % get the bounding box

% display
figure; imshow( img );
hold on; rectangle('Position', rect );
```

I used this code to crop a rectangular image but it doesn't work. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the first line, "mg" should be "img", and I removed the extra spaces from your URL. After I made these changes, your code produced a perfect bounding box.

When you claim that the code does not work, what precisely is the problem?

Comment: Thank you very much sir... The problem is that it returns back my original image without cropping. I am actually using the codes on a bank note on my computer, not necessarily the URL image.

Comment: That is certainly possible -- a different image might reverse the foreground and background. However, the image you supplied worked without changing the ">" to "<".

Comment: Yes... Even Some of my images still reversed it, and it didn't work on all. Than you once again.